# I can't pull autharization from header

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am doing auth using passportjs, but when the client tries to pull the token, it gives an error.

```
import jwt from "express-jwt"
const getTokenFromHeaders  = (req) => {
    const {headers : {authorization}} = req

    if(authorization &&  authorization.spilt(' ')[0] === 'Token' ){
        return authorization.split(' ')[1]
    }
    return null
}
```

this console

```
file:///C:/Users/atala/Desktop/atalayapp-main/backend/middleware/auth/auth.js:3
    const {headers : {authorization}} = req
                                        ^

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
        at getTokenFromHeaders (file:///C:/Users/Desktop/atalayapp-main/backend/middleware/auth/auth.js:3:41)
        at file:///C:/Users/Desktop/atalayapp-main/backend/middleware/auth/auth.js:15:20
        at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
        at async Promise.all (index 0)
        at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:385:24)
        at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
        at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
    > Blockquote
```

Comment: how do you call `getTokenFromHeaders` ?

Comment: Did you pass `req` to the function when calling it?